# Azure mobile app backend / Azure AD B2C and aspnet core web client

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

I have a xamarin forms app using azure mobile app backend integrating with ADD B2C.

Following this guide: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app)

Authenticating B2C first and login Azure Mobile App after using previous token. Everything OK!!

Now i want to have a aspnet core web client sharing backend and authentication process.

Standard aspnet core template, works very well with B2C. So i need to login in Azure mobile app to have same userid on web and mobile app.

I know there is Azure mobile app js SDK, buy i need some sample to integrate in aspnet core template and B2c.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you use the same Client ID and client secret across both, and they will both use the same backend authentication. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/